# Equations in Bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown

I cannot seem to make this work.  My equation looks like this in plain text:

```
P[C] >= MPC
```

I can use this to get some display:

`P[C] >= MPC`

but when I try, what I think the book is suggesting:

```
$$P\left[C\right]\ \ge\ MPC$$
```

I do not get an equation but a reprint of the text inside the dollar signs.

If I knit the single page with equations I get the correct equation:

```
P[C] ≥ MPC
```

Why can I not get the equation to work creel;y in the bookdown book?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I provided the code above.  What additional would I need to make a valid example?  Does this require a full .Rmd file?  A full bookdown book?  A screenshot?

Comment: Something that I can run on my computer to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I am working on an example.  One thing I noticed is that if I use the build book commands the equations do not render correctly as I stated.  If I however us the knit button in Rstudio, the equations render correctly.